# Appending binary string to NSMutableData

Tags: ios, nsmutabledata

How would I go about appending this binary string

**111000111000111111000111000111**

to an `NSMutableData` object that contains a `png` 
(`NSMutableData *dataForPNGFile = UIImagePNGRepresentation(p.Image);`)

Comment: You want to append that exact bit representation to the end of some NSMutableData object?  It's 30 bits, so that ain't gonna happen exactly.  At best, you will have to toss in two bits of padding on one side or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to parse the string into an `NSData`, then append that.

I'm not aware of anything built in, so e.g.

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength(string.length+7)/8];
uint8_t *mutableBytes = (uint8_t *)data.mutableBytes;

for(NSUinteger index = 0; index < string.length; index++)
{
    unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:index];
    mutableBytes[index >> 3] <<= 1;
    if(character == '1') mutableBytes[index >> 3] |= 1;
}

if(string.length&7)
    mutableBytes[string.length >> 3] <<= (7 - (string.length&7));
```

So assumptions are that your source string is only 1s and 0s, that it's written from most significant to least significant digit and that it's byte rather than word oriented.

Also, `UIImagePNGRepresentation` returns immutable data so you'll need to take a mutable copy of that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the NSMuteableData method appendBytes:length:

You will have to convert your bits to bytes as @Tommy says.